# Wait for multiple database calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Having trouble wrapping a loop in a promise

I need to make an array of users before i render my page but i cant seem to figure out how to wrap my database calls

Thanks in advance.

```
router.get('/friends', auth.isLogged(), (req, res) => {
    let friendsList = [];

    User.findById(req.user._id,
        {
            friends: 1,
        },
        (err, user) => {
            user.friends.map(friend => {
                User.findById(friend._id).then(doc => {
                    friendsList.push(doc);
                });
            });
            console.log(friendsList); <-- gets called before the loop is done
        });
});
```

Comment: `gets called before the loop is done` - yes, because `User.findById` is asynchronous ...

Comment: What is your data layer? If you're using mongoose you could potentially use `populate()` instead of doing this at all.

Comment: I use mongoose, i will check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn the `friends` into an array of promises, and await a `Promise.all` over all of them, like this:

```
router.get('/friends', auth.isLogged(), (req, res) => {
  let friendsList = [];
  User.findById(req.user._id, {
      friends: 1,
    },
    async (err, user) => {
      const friendsList = await Promise.all(
        user.friends.map(({ _id }) => User.findById(_id))
      );
      console.log(friendsList);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Works perfect, ty!

Answer (score 0):

wrap it in `Promise.all()`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

`Promise.all()` doesn't resolve until all the promises are resolved or one i rejected.

Comment: of course, the callback to `.map` will need to **return a promise** - just `"wrap it all in Promise.all"` doesn't exactly help - what is "it all" for example??

Comment: I know how to work with promise.all when i have single functions that each one returns a promise but here i have a map function and i cant seem to figure out how to wrap it

Comment: you can return a promise from your map function - and pass the resulting array into `Promise.all` -- i.e. `Promise.all(items.map(..))`  -- In this situation, you're trying to use a method that's designed to return 1 item to return many items.  My assumption is `findById` is not correct for this use case.

Comment: @AsafAviv glad you got it solved but I said the same thing and got downvoted!

Comment: @jsw324 I didnt downvote you, the chosen answer gave a perfect solution with code ready to be used, its easier to understand CertainPerformance answer from your answer because he gave me a the code for it

Comment: I definitely agree. He had the better answer. Thanks and good luck!